# TensorFlow in-graph replication example

Tags: tensorflow

I want to experiment with TensorFlow's in-graph replication in a multi GPU cluster with multiple ps and workers. The [CIFAR-10 multi GPU example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) shows in graph synchronous replication on a single machine. Is there an example available which I can refer to like the [example trainer program for between-graph training](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/distributed/index.html)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking, we prefer between-graph replication over in-graph replication for distributed training, because between-graph replication is more scalable that (the current implementation of) in-graph replication. The main problem with in-graph replication is that it currently requires you to build multiple copies of the graph structure for your network and materialize them at a single location (i.e. the distributed master). When you have hundreds of replicas, this turns the master into a bottleneck; by contrast in between-graph replication each replica only has a copy of the graph that runs locally.

The downside of between-graph replication is that it makes synchronous training more difficult, because you now have multiple training loops to synchronize, rather than a single loop with a single training op. The `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` used in the [distributed Inception trainer](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/85ccd4a369711b64052a85e7fff999510e829c1e/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py#L197) provides one way to do synchronous training with between-graph replication.

However, if you want to try in-graph replication, you could do it by modifying [the line that assigns a device to each of the towers](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/931ff427f3a55a9c6c734a4c325d6af1b53665c3/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L175) in the CIFAR-10 example. Instead of assigning the tower to different GPUs in the same process, you can assign them to different GPUs in *different worker tasks*. For example:

```
worker_devices = ["/job:worker/task:0/gpu:0", ..., "/job:worker/task:7/gpu:0"]

for worker_device in worker_devices:
  with tf.device(worker_device):
    # Execute code for building the model replica.
```

Comment: Hi, @mrry  can you explain what exactly replica is ? Thx!

Comment: Is that something  to do with replication in paper of [Parameter Server for Distributed Machine Learning](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~muli/file/ps.pdf) ?

Comment: I found this article (https://clindatsci.com/blog/2017/5/31/distributed-tensorflow) is helpful as complimentary material.