# Distributed Tensorflow Training of Reinpect Human detection model

Tags: computer-vision, tensorflow, distributed, multi-gpu

I am working on Distributed Tensorflow, particularly the implementation of Reinspect model using Distributed Tensorflow given in the following paper https://github.com/Russell91/TensorBox .

We are using Between-graph-Asynchronous implementation of Distributed tensorflow settings but the results are very surprising. While bench marking, we have come to see that Distributed training takes almost more than 2 times more training time than a single machine training. Any leads about what could be happening and what else could be tried be would be really appreciated. Thanks

Note: There is a correction in the post, we are using between-graph implementation not in-graph implementation. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I wouldn't be surprised if moving from a single-process implementation of a model to a multi-machine implementation would lead to a slowdown. From your question, it's not obvious what might be going on, but here are a few general pointers:

- If the model has a large number of parameters relative to the amount of computation (e.g. if it mostly performs large matrix multiplications rather than convolutions), then you may find that the network is the bottleneck. What is the bandwidth of your network connection?
- Are there a large number of copies between processes, perhaps due to unfortunate device placement? Try collecting and visualizing a timeline to see what is going on when you run your model.
- You mention that you are using "in-graph replication", which is [not currently recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39681588/3574081) for scalability. In-graph replication can create a bottleneck at the single master, especially when you have a large model graph with many replicas.
- Are you using a single input pipeline across the replicas or multiple input pipelines? Using a single input pipeline would create a bottleneck at the process running the input pipeline. (However, with in-graph replication, running multiple input pipelines could also create a bottleneck as there would be one Python process driving the I/O with a large number of threads.)
- Or are you using the feed mechanism? Feeding data is much slower when it has to cross process boundaries, as it would in a replicated setting. Using between-graph replication would at least remove the bottleneck at the single client process, but to get better performance you should use an input pipeline. (As [Yaroslav observed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39809719/3574081), feeding and fetching large tensor values is slower in the distributed version because the data is transferred via RPC. In a single process these would use a simple `memcpy()` instead.)
- How many processes are you using? What does the scaling curve look like? Is there an immediate slowdown when you switch to using a parameter server and single worker replica (compared to a single combined process)? Does the performance get better or worse as you add more replicas?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at similar thing recently, and I noticed that moving data from grpc into Python runtime is slower than expected. In particular consider following pattern

```
add_op = params.assign_add(update)
...
sess.run(add_op)
```

If `add_op` lies on a different process, then `sess.run` adds a decoding step that happens at rate of 50-100 MB/second.

Here's a [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/1124bb02a9fd4abce3d86caf2f950cb2) and [relevant discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4498)